# I am using kubuntu and when I boot up it automatically shuts down after 2 3 minutes

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu, shutdown

I am using kubuntu and when I boot up it automatically shuts down after 2 3 minutes. It started a month ago so back then it used to happen after every 15-30 minutes so I tried changing the nvidia drivers from 470 to 450 to now 515 but it ain't solving the thing. Then I started using older kernel version so It increased time of shutdown loop but didn't stop!

Comment: Perhaps you need to take it to a repair service.

Comment: Typically only one nVidia driver is correct for each card/chip. And if you did not purge before installing another, you may have conflicts. Always purge first. `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` then `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` But you may just need to clean all the dog hair out of fans?